# Django error TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am a bit new to python and I am trying to consume an external API serialized with a serializer class within my Django project and I am getting the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

 "GET /project/v1/mypath/ HTTP/1.1" 500 56241
```

see my view below

```
import requests as requests
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .config import *
from .serializer import *

BASE_URL = BASE_URL
ACCOUNT_URL = "{}/v2/account".format(BASE_URL)
ORDERS_URL = "{}/v2/orders".format(BASE_URL)
HEADERS = {'APCA-API-KEY-ID': API_KEY, 'APCA-API-SECRET-KEY': SECRET_KEY}


# Create your views here.
class BrokerGetAccountView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BrokerAccountSerializer
    queryset = BrokerAccount.objects.all()

    def get_account(self):
        r = requests.get(ACCOUNT_URL, headers=HEADERS)
        serializer = BrokerAccountSerializer(r.json(), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Honestly, I have no idea where the error is coming from
Please advise me on how I can resolve this and where the error is
coming from

Also which `__init__()` is the error referring to?

EDITS
I edited the code in the question  implemented suggestions made by @bdbd
now only empty array ([]) is returned

Please advise me on how to actually get data

Comment: Well, as it suggests, two arguments are given when only one is expected. Note that for `self`, you don't actually pass is an argument (it gets passed 'internally').

Comment: error shows `/v1/` but you have code with `/v2/` - maybe you run different code.

Comment: is this FULL error message? It doesn't show which line of your code makes problem. You may use `print(...)` between lines to see which `print` will be displayed before error and which after error - this way you may localize line which makes problem.

Comment: You are passing a `requests.Response` object to a DRF serializer, why do you expect that would work? Also the first positional argument is normally something you want to serialize not something you want to deserialize. Honestly it is not clear what you are even trying to do here...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, Please advise me with a code snippet that shows me  how best to consume the API. I mentioned that I am new to python django, Any help would be appreciated

Comment: thanks @furas, i did what ou advised and i see that the error is from def get_account(self):

Comment: @MIikeEps `def get_account(self):` should be `def get_account(self, request):` if that is a viewset action (there may be more kwargs passed according to url pattern for it).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, did what you said(i also edited the code in question). but  still getting the same error

Comment: the only idea that problem makes `AlpacaAccountSerializer` - you run it with two values so it runs its `__init__()` with two values - and error says `...but 2 were given
`. And it is inside function `get_account`

Comment: Change `request.get` to `requests.get`. You forgot the extra `s` if you were looking to use requests library to use `get`.

Comment: I edited the code in the question  implemented suggestions made by @bdbd
now only empty array ([]) is returned

Please advise me on how to actually get data

Comment: If you are using it in the serializer, then you probably are expecting json data. `r` is just the response object you got so that will not work. What you want is in `r.content`, but to get the json representation, you can simply use `r.json()`.

Comment: @bdbd, I tried it, but i still get an empty array as a response :(

Comment: Can you check what response you received?

Comment: empty array ([]) is returned

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help
I eventually solved it this way,

```
import json

import requests as requests
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .serializer import *
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer


# Create your views here.

@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
def BrokerGetAccountView(request):
    import BrokerTrade.config
    BASE_URL = BrokerTrade.config.BASE_URL
    ACCOUNT_URL = "{}/v2/account".format(BASE_URL)
    ORDERS_URL = "{}/v2/orders".format(BASE_URL)
    HEADERS = {'APCA-API-KEY-ID': BrokerTrade.config.API_KEY, 'APCA-API-SECRET-KEY': BrokerTrade.config.SECRET_KEY}

    request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', '')
    r = requests.get(ACCOUNT_URL, headers=HEADERS)

    jsonData = r.json()
    # print(jsonData)
    serializer = BrokerAccountSerializer(data=jsonData)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(serializer.data)
```